# How to write a setup.py with a different file name?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I'm trying to package my python program with setup.py(setuptools). It's working. But if I rename the setup.py to other file name, the package will be created without a setup.py. Then when you try to install that package, there will be an error. Is there any way to solve the rename problem?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve by renaming `setup.py`? Also think about this: how should `setuptools` know where to find the package installation instructions in a directory full of files? There should be some file that will serve as the initial point, and that file is called `setup.py`.

Comment: It's okay to have the setup.py in the package, but I have a limitation that I can't have a setup.py in the source directory. So what I do now is to create a setup.py symbolic link from the actual to_be_renamed_setup.py, make the package and then delete the symbolic link. When you run 'python to_be_renamed_setup.py sdist', the program should be able to find out and create the actual setup.py required in the package?

Comment: This question is legit. There can be a directory (say, the root dir of a source repo) that contains enough code to create multiple related distributions, and each distribution needs its own setup script. It should be possible because when `python my-xxx-setup.py sdist` executes, it knows the filename is my-xxx-setup.py, so it could write that down into the distribution.